# I want to get max id value from table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

in model file i write this code:

```
public function maxcode() 
{
    $this->db->select (max(ClassID)+1 as ClassID)-> from ('class');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows>0)
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row;
     } 
     echo $row['ClassID'];

}
```

in controller function i write.....this code

```
public function maxcode() 
{ 

 $this->insert->maxcode(); 
}
```

Comment: so what's the issue? are you not getting the `max` value?

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what your problem is.
You need to transfer this value to the template. This is done in the page controller 
Example

```
$data['ClassID'] = $this->insert->maxcode();
$this->view('tenplate Name', $data);
```

And used in template

```
<?php echo $ClassID; ?>
```

Comment: Is this your answer? Don't ask questions here. You should comment it.

Comment: i want when the page load in CLass ID text box i want  to get auto next value from database..but i can get it using this code

Comment: Then you need to use "autoincrement". In the database, assign the autoincrement property to the "ClassId" column and when creating new rows, the ID will be created automatically and you will not need to specify it in the query

Comment: in database i define it autoincrement but when i make a view of class form then i use this <label>Class ID</label>
           
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cid" > now tell how i get next value when form load

Comment: Specify you need to return the maximum value that is or the next unoccupied?
And also what exactly do you fail? Does not rotate the result or how?

Comment: i need maximum value from database and i am failing in displaying max value of class id in my form textbox